# Java throws NumberFormatException error after BufferedReader.read for char

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to write a simple program. I am trying to get two user input, first one is of type char and second one is of type integer. I am using BufferedReader for taking user input. However after taking char input from user when I am pressing enter it is throwing below error.

```
Please enter your sex: m
Please enter your code: Please enter your salary: Exception in thread "main" jav
a.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at classtest.main(classtest.java:24)
```

To my surprise if I am taking integer input first and then char then it is not giving any error. however if I am taking char input first and then integer then it is giving error. As soon as I am pressing enter key it is throwing error. It is not even asking for second input. It is considering the input as "".

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class classtest 
{ 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{           
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int empcode;

char sex;

System.out.print("Please enter your sex: ");                        
sex=(char)System.in.read();

System.out.print("Please enter your code: ");       
empcode=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());        
System.out.print("Code: " +empcode);         
System.out.print("Sex: " + sex);            
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `InputStream.read()` returns a `byte`, not a `char`. If you want a `char`, you should wrap it in an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: NumberFormatException: For input string: "" is a clear enough message. What do you not understand about it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `br.readLine()` to get the sex, and use `String.charAt(0)` to get the first character of it (with appropriate checking, of course):

```
sex = '?';
while (sex != 'M' && sex != 'F') {
  System.out.print("Please enter your sex: ");
  String line = br.readLine();
  if (line.length() == 1) {
    sex = line.charAt(0);
  }
}
```

Currently, your call to `br.readLine()` is reading the contents of `System.in` from immediately after the single-character sex up to the newline following it. I guess you are entering something like `F\n` - so `br.readLine` is reading the empty string between `F` and the `\n` exclusively.

Comment: I am entering a value "M" for sex and hitting enter key. I am not entering \n etc. However as soon as I am hitting entering enter key it is throwing error. It is taking input for the empcode as "".

Comment: What character do you think the enter key types?